# How to add drop-down controls to navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-spinner, drawerlayout, android-drawer

As per the title.

I am using the Support Library DrawerLayout to create a sliding drawer that has a listview in it.

I'd like to add some drop-down (spinner) controls so the list can be sorted alphabetically etc.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Instead of adding just listview, try to add one linearlayout vertically aligned containing one listview and one spinner.

Comment: Literally just done this :) How do I go about setting up the spinner to order my listview alphabetically etc?

Comment: let's assume other options to change order. In *OnItemSelectedListener()*, according to position of spinner item, call `Collections.sort(list/arraylist)` and notify your adapter about new sorted list